# What does "Bless you" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “What's that?” said Ron, pointing at a large dish of some sort of shellfish stew that stood beside a large steak-and-kidney pudding.
>
> “Bouillabaisse,” said Hermione.
>
> “**Bless you**,” said Ron.
>
> “It's French,” said Hermione, “I had it on holiday summer before last.
>   It's very nice.”

One of the dictionaries I've consulted says "Bless you" can be used to express "thanks", which I think it could be the author intended to mean for this context. But I don't have confidence. What does it truly mean?

Comment: A similar response from another generation might be for Ron to say "sorry I don't follow Pokemon" but that wouldn't suit the Potter universe.

Comment: Nice find! I've now edited one dictionary to include this sense: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bless_you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sydney's answer is right in that "bless you" is what you say in English after someone sneezes, but I don't think it addresses why it was said in this context.

In American English at least, it's a pretty common joke to say "bless you" after someone says a weird word, like `bouillabaisse`. The word doesn't have to sound anything like a sneeze, it just needs to be uncommon or have a weird pronunciation.

Think of the motivation for it like, "What you just said sounds like gibberish," as if the person sneezed.

I personally haven't heard it used too much outside of books and film and other media, but that doesn't mean you can't use it in conversation.

Comment: @insidesin it's no problem at all. It's a very valid reason to include "American" to his answer because he simply doesn't know if it's the same in British English or any other English because there could be differences. And yes, an Indian English speaker might very well mention that he is Indian

Comment: @insidesin - Much of English is regional, so there is nothing wrong with qualifying an answer with something like, _"In American English..."_ or _"In Indian English..."_ or even _"In some parts of New South Wales..."_ It's often helpful information.

Answer (score 35):

Many people say 'bless you' after someone else sneezes. Ron thinks (or pretends to think) that 'bouillabaisse' sounds like a sneeze. Maybe the joke would work better if Hermione had said 'schnitzel'.

(Many languages have a word or phrase like this, many of which are based on wishing health or God's blessing (of health): see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responses_to_sneezing).)

Comment: It's a pretty common joke to say "bless you" when someone says a word that sounds weird.

Comment: @TheWanderer, Even if it doesn't sound like a sneeze at all?

Comment: @dan really anything. I don't think I've heard it used that much outside of books or film, though.

Comment: I like to do this with the name Saskatchewan. But it can be done with any strange word.

Comment: Consider who the jokester is:  Ron.  It's hardly cosmopolitan humor ;)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo in the context of the Triwizard tournament, "gesundheit" would have been a better joke ;)

Comment: @alephzero: but "gesundheit" after a sneeze is not widely known in the UK: really only from American media.

Comment: Ron isn't trying to say that "bouillabaisse" sounds like a sneeze (it obviously doesn't); the key is what @TheWanderer said: "it's a pretty common joke to say "bless you" when someone says a word that sounds weird". This is the answer!

Comment: @ColinFine I guess it depends where in the UK you come from. I've known it for half a century, and I have no idea where I learned it - but almost certainly *not* from American media.

Comment: @alephzero I would,agree with Colin Fine from my part of the UK 30 miles away from London, gesundheit is a thing that I know from American media. Perhaps in areas where American influence due to such as Military bases like RAF  Milldenhall or RAF Chicksands is common it may have spread to the local people?

Comment: [Here](https://youtu.be/f3h0p2sxGVg?t=62) is another example of the same joke (using "gesundheit", which is the German/Yiddish equivalent to "Bless You") from Tangled, when Rapunzel introduces herself.

Comment: I remember 'gesundheit' from the punchline of a schoolyard joke (Australia, mid-1970s), in which Hitler is reviewing troops and someone sneezes. When no-one admits who it was, he orders increasing portions of the troops shot. Finally a  soldier in the remaining portion admits it was him, and Hitler says ... I can't remember if I figured out the meaning from context, or whether I asked, or whether I just laughed because everyone else did.

Comment: Incidentally, there is a story, perhaps apocryphal, that the origin of saying "bless you!" when someone sneezes is because during the Black Death, sneezing meant you would be dead within a day or two.

Comment: @Michael: I had that at the back of my mind, but decided to keep it simple. It is not necessary to consider the origins of saying "Bless you" in English, simply to say that it's a wish for God's blessing of health. Various other languages have similar expressions, and they can't all have arisen out of the Black Death.